# Using related_name to return queryset not working in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, foreign-keys

Here I am working with two models.Both models have `ForeignKey` relation to the `User` model. Here I wanted to query `staffs`, `is_reviewed_by` and `sent_by` and I tried like this. When I do filter it returns the queryset but when I used `related_name` to query then it throws  `AttributeError`.

How can i do this?

> `Exception Value: 
>   'Leave' object has no attribute 'reviewed_by

models.py

```
class Leave(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='staff_leave')
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='staff_leave')
    sub = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    msg = models.TextField()
    start_day = models.DateField()
    end_day = models.DateField()
    is_reviewed_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='reviewed_by',blank=True,null=True)

class LeaveReply(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='leave_status')
    leave = models.ForeignKey(Leave,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='leave_status')
    sub = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
    msg = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    sent_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    sent_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='sent_by')
```

views.py

```
def leave_detail(request, pk):
    leave = get_object_or_404(Leave, pk=pk)
    reviewers = leave.reviewed_by.all() # not working
    staffs = leave.staff_leave.all() # does not works

    staffs = Leave.objects.filter(staff=leave.staff) # this works
    reviewers = Leave.objects.filter(is_reviewed_by=leave.is_reviewed_by)  # works

    reply_sender = LeaveReply.objects.filter(sent_by=leave.is_reviewed_by) #works 

    reply_sender = leave.sent_by.all() # doesn't works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're a bit confused. There is nothing to do with related_name here.

You have a Leave object. As the error says, Leave items don't have `reviewed_by`, `sent_by` or `staff_leave` attributes. They have `is_reviewed_by` and `staff`; and the only `sent_by` object is on the LeaveReply object.

Comment: how can i get query then

Comment: Which query? As I said, for the first two you should just use the attributes you defined on the model. I don't know what you are expecting to do with `sent_by`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited answer**

models:

```
class Leave(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='staff_leave')
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='staff_leave')  
    is_reviewed_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='reviewed_by',blank=True,null=True)
```

I think this model is for Leave details of employee.

**Not working code:**

```
reviewers = leave.reviewed_by.all() # not working
staffs = leave.staff_leave.all() # does not works
```

And this is for, staff who is taking leave and a person who reviewed the leave application. Both fields are related to User model. If we have instance of `Leave` model (i.e. `leave = get_object_or_404(Leave, pk=pk)`), then we can get these two by this:

```
staffs = leave.staff # for person who will be on leave
reviewers = leave.is_reviewed_by # for the person who reviewed the leave
```

**Extra**

If we have a **User** instance (`user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)`), and we want to know how many leaves he has taken, then we can use related name:

```
no_of_leaves_itaken = user.staff_leave.all()
```

or how many leaves he has reviewed:

```
no_of_leaves_reviewed = user.staff_leave.all()
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanations on how the above snippet attempts to answer the question?

Comment: Hi @AndrewNaguib, sorry for this type of answer. I edited my answer. thanks for notifying.